# Eigenvectors of a matrix (Solving and Plotting)

Tags: plotting, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Given a nxn matrix h[k]

```
(h[k_] = ReplacePart[DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[a + c, n]] +DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[b, n - 1], 1] + DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[b, n - 1], -1], {{1, 1} -> a , {n, n} -> a }]) // MatrixForm
```

Where `a=a(k)` and `b=b(k)`are functions of k and c is an integer , they are defined as the following :

```
a=4(ja*(1-Cos[k]*Cos[k])+je)+2*je;
b=-2*Cos[k]*2*je;
c=2*je;
```

Assuming that

```
je=ja=1
```

***First Question***

I'm trying to diagonalize the matrix `h[k]` to get the i-th eigenvalues `E_i` and the i-th eigenvectors `V_i` where $i$ is a number in the range `{1,n}`.

Taking `n=3`so the dimension of the matrix h[k] is `3x3`.

To simplify the calculation let us consider that `k=0` (for now), the matrix `h[0]` will look like :

```
h[0]={{6., -4., 0.}, {-4., 8., -4.}, {0., -4., 6.}}
```

I compared the above calculated matrix `h[0]` with another matrix `m` with inserting the inputs 6 , -4 , 8....(etc) manually.

The eigenvalues `V_i` of `h[0]` and `m`, were identical.

````
  ```{12.7446, 6., 1.25544}```
````

But the eigenvectors are different:

The eigenvectors of the calculated matrix `h[0]` are (calculated by `Eigenvectors[h[0]]`):

```
 {{-0.454401,0.766185, -0.454401}, {0.707107, -9.42055*10^-16, -0.707107},{0.541774, 0.642621, 0.541774}}
```

On the other hand, `Eigenvectors[m]` returns:

```
{{1, 1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[41]), 1}, {-3, 0, 2}, {1, 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[41]), 1}}
```

I noticed that the eigenvectors of m-matrix are the corrected ones compared with `h[0]`, I didn't know what is the error in the `h[k]` matrix (I think the problem is caused by the `ReplacePart` function or something in the first `h[k]`). How can I solve this?

***Second Question***

I want to plot the eigenvectors of `h[k]` as k varies from 0 to Pi (for a given k) in two forms:

1- Histogram
2- Sinusoidal plot

For example 3x3 h[k] matrix would have the eigenvectors *V_i={v1,v2,v3}* and *vi={y1,y2,y3}* so the amplitudes of `v_i` are taken as y-variables and the `i` as x-variables.

Comment: In the replace part in the definition of h[k] you have `{{1, 1} -> a +,`. That looks like incomplete input. Could you check your code?

Comment: I suspect that you did not construct `m` and `h[0]` to be *exactly* the same. I think you built `m` by hand with exact numbers, while `h[0]` contains machine-precision numbers. This makes a difference to the results returned by `Eigenvectors`: in fact, that function will return normalized eigenvectors for numerical input (like `h[0]`) but non-normalized ones for exact or symbolic input (like `m`). You can confirm that by running `Normalize /@ N@ Eigenvectors[m]`. The eigenvectors fill be numerically the same (up to the sign).

Comment: So m and h[0] wouldn't have the same eigenvectors however the inputs look the same ? Then h[0] has the right eigenvectors?